# Using `firstOption` with slick 3

Tags: scala, slick

I am trying to run a query like `.filter(_.id === 1).firstOption` but the compiler complains there is no symbol `firstOption`. Was this removed in slick 3? What can I use instead?

Comment: As an aside, you'll probably find the [migration guide](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/upgrade.html#first) helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To limit the number of results before calling result, use `take(num)`. For example like this:

```
val result: Future[Option[Whatever]] = db.run((query.filter(_.id === 1).take(1)).result).map(_.headOption)
```

According to the official docs, the above statement boils down using `headOption` on the result method.

```
val result: Future[Option[Whatever]] = db.run((query.filter(_.id === 1)).result.headOption)
```

`query.result` returns an object of type `DBIOAction`. An action in slick is something that can be executed on a database. The actual execution is done by passing the action to `db.run()` or `db.stream()`. You can find a more detailed explanation here: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/api/index.html#slick.dbio.DBIOAction

Comment: But `head` and `headOption` only work after calling `result` on a query

Comment: `.headOption` as used in this sample is not the same thing as the original `.firstOption`, as it's being called on a `Seq` instead of a `Query`. First paragraph is wrong.

Comment: You're absolutely right Alexandru, sorry for the confusion. The updated solution should work though.

Comment: So how can you use firstOption instead of headOption?

Comment: Tried again, hopefully this time it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Roman, I think you should just delete the update markers - SO has revisions history for these replies anyway, so no need to indicate how the reply evolved IMHO.

Comment: I ran across this comment and mistakenly concluded that .take(1) and .headOption yield identical results in Slick.  In case anyone else finds this helpful:  take(1) translates to LIMIT 1, while headOption uses JDBC Statement.setMaxRows(1).  The internet seems to think these are mostly similar, but there are apparently cases where the former is more useful to the query optimizer and can thus be more efficient.  In our case, we use Postgres, and we had a "headOption" query that was eating up our server's CPU completely, until we added "take(1)", and the difference was dramatic!